# postfix/dovecot on ubuntu Thunderbird client can't save messages to sent folder

Tags: thunderbird, postfix, dovecot

My problem is that TB can't save messages to the Sent folder In users home directories there are mail folders which in turn have Maildir folders so the actual mail directory for users is mail/Maildir I've tried adjusting this value in Advanced settings but TB can't save to Sent folder
`lsb_release -a`
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

Using Thunderbird 78.14.0 64 bit

Comment: Add to your post what **Linux distro and version** you're running on your machine and the **Thunderbird version** too.